# Desktop Icons not showing on desktop

Tags: icons, desktop-icons

Just installed Ubuntu 14 and I'm brand new to it. I have programs that are installed I see when I search but do not show in the dock to the left or on the desktop. How do I add desktop icons? I tried dragging and I looked for some way to do this by right clicking on the icon and see no way to do it. I found old posts (for V12) that say to go to advanced setting but I just see settings and there is nothing there. How do I get to advanced setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Open the File Manager (`nautilus`) and go to `Files` -> `Enter Location` or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Type `/usr/share/applications` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, **copy** the required applications and paste them on the Desktop.

You can now open these applications by double-clicking on them.